# Make tooltip appear clear icon in v-text-field using v-tooltip (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, tooltip, v-tooltip

I'm interested in creating a tooltip for the clear icon within the v-text-field. Could you please provide guidance on how to achieve this?

```
          <v-text-field
            ref="newSearchField"
            v-model="text"
            class="search-input"
            :class="{
              'rounded-r-lg': $vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown,
              'rounded-l-lg': $vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly
            }"
            type="text"
            solo
            :label="label"
            :disabled="disabled"
            :placeholder="label"
            persistent-placeholder
            autofocus
            data-test="search-input"
            hide-details
            clearable
            autocomplete="off"
            @keyup="nextItem"
            @click:clear="
              clear()
              $nuxt.$data.layoutName === 'home' ? (text = '') : $emit('clear')
            "
            @input="autocomplete"
            @keydown="blured = false"
            @focus="blured = false"
          >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the class of the clear icon (`.v-field__clearable`) to the [`:activator`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tooltip/#props-activator) prop of v-tooltip:

```html
<v-tooltip activator=".v-field__clearable">clear input</v-tooltip>
```

Make sure that the selector references a single element, for example by using a class on the v-text-field (in your example, you could do `.search-input .v-field__clearable`).

See how it works in the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  template: `
      <v-app>
        <v-main>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="msg"
            class="search-input"
            clearable
          />
          <v-tooltip activator=".search-input .v-field__clearable">
              clear it
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-main>
      </v-app>
  `,
  setup(){
    return {
      msg: ref('hello world')
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```